# PHP using count() with array

Tags: php

Im trying to get the amount of elements in an array using the count() function, the result is a bit puzzling to me, considere the following example.

Assume that the user ID provided is wrong, and therefore had no matches, wouldnt then the result of the count function be 0? yet it is 1. can you explain to me why?

thanks

```
$q = mysql_query("select password from users where user_name = '" .  $userID   .   "'");
$check = mysql_fetch_array($q);

$result = count($check);

echo "RESULT:" . $result;
```

Comment: Debugging the code would give you some insight into what $result actually is. Also, don't forget your friend is_array().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the wrong way to count rows in a result set.  First of all, from the documentation on [mysql_fetch_array()](http://us.php.net/mysql_fetch_array)

> Returns an array of strings that
>   corresponds to the fetched row, or
>   FALSE  if there are no more rows.

Ergo, if we do this

```
echo count( false );
```

We can see the output is `1`.  Why?  Because the [count()](http://us.php.net/count) documentation tells us that as well

> If var is not an array or an object
>   with implemented Countable interface,
>   1 will be returned.

To do a proper count, use [mysql_num_rows()](http://us.php.net/mysql_num_rows)

```
$q = mysql_query("select password from users where user_name = '" .  $userID   .   "'");
$result = mysql_num_rows( $q );

if ( 0 == $result )
{
  // no rows in result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`count()` returns 1 because in case of failure `$check` is not an array.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php):

> If var is not an array or an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned

But you should anyway handle error cases directly (if the query fails your code shouldn't even get to the point where you analize its results). Also as other have correctly said, that's not how you count the number of results a query returns as that's what `mysql_num_rows()` is for

Answer (score 1):

use [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) instead of count. [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) returns 1 for the value `FALSE`

Comment: $numrows = mysql_num_rows($q);

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array` returns false if there are no more rows. `count(false)` = 1.

Try using `mysql_num_rows` if you want to count the number of results.